# Bootstrap cols not in one row

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have an issue with `col` that aren't in one row. I have all of them in one container, row and 3 columns `col-md-5`, `col-md-2` and `col-md-5`. All paddings and margins are set from CSS bootstrap.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <div>
        <div class="col-md-5 col-xs-12">
          <div>
            <div class="row-7 clearfix">
              <p class="text">Výtečně<br>chutnám</p>
              <img class="text-2" src="../images/unk.png" alt="!" title="!">
            </div>
            <div class="button-holder">Koupit</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-12 mobile-hide">
          <div class="line"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-5 col-xs-12">
          <p class="text-3">TEXT</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Dev page here: http://dev.ekolok.cz/

Thank you for advice and help.

Comment: What's the desired output?

Comment: nothing but `.col[XY]` is allowed directly underneath `.row`. additionally there shouldn't be something like `.row-7`. That sould be `.col-7 > .row`.

Comment: plus: `col-xs-12` is completely optional if you use any other col definition. that means: `col-md-2` will always span 12 if the viewport is lower than `md`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what exactly your layout should look like but here is how bootstrap column layout should look:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4"></div>
    <div class="col-md-4"></div>
    <div class="col-md-4"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem in your code is that columns aren't a direct child of row etc.
Try to refactor the code and see if you understand what is going on...

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap columns must add up to 12 per row. If you would like multiple elements in a row, your 'col-whatevers' must add up to 12.

For example if you want your title and your button on the same row your code would need to look like this:

```
 <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-6">
                <p class="text">Výtečně<br>chutnám</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-6">
                <img class="text-2" src="../images/unk.png" alt="!" title="!">
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

You would then need to add another 'row' element and fill that up with columns that add up to 12. Not sure if this is what you're asking but it's what I could make out from your question.

Also, empty 'divs' are redundant, it doesn't mean anything. You can remove all your  tags that don't carry a class, id etc.